# How to make a link unclickable

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins, hyperlink

Im using this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-visual-slidebox-builder/ for my website that creates an overlay on a picture with some text on it. The text is always clickable. In the settings of the plugin there is a field to put which link it redirects to. But even if I leave it empty the link is still clickable and redirects to undifined.html which is a page that doesnt exist. Is there something I can put in the field that does nothing when clicked? I can put a # in the field that kinda helps but it still scrolls all the way to the top. I tried looking in the source of the plugin to delete the linking but couldnt find anything. Apparently more people are having this issue http://wordpress.org/support/topic/delete-title-link?replies=7

Comment: Maybe you can apply the CSS rule `pointer-events:none;` on the appropriate elements to disable the links ? It works well on modern browsers.

Comment: Im looking for something to put in the field where i normally would put the link. Does something like this exist? # does the job pretty well but it still scrolls to the top of the page. I want it to do completely nothing.

Comment: Solved it. Well solved... I couldnt just put text in the field because it automatically put .html at the end of it. So I just put javascript: and now it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A JQuery solution would be to use the .on() to cancel the click event.

For example:

HTML

```
<div id="link_container">
  <a class="no_clicky" href="#">This link doesn't work.</a>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#link_container').on('click','.no_clicky', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Documentation for .on()

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I dont have access to the html the plugin creates. I just choose how I want the image to be in the gui and it creates a shortcode for me to use. I have thought of disabling the linking in the source of the plugin since it only consists of 2 php and 3 css files. But I couldnt find anything apart from the field where you put the link in. Deleting this field doesnt do anything since a blank field just makes the text direct to undefined.html